# Mysql query can not retrieve data as per condition

Tags: php, mysql

I have one issue. I need to retrieve data from database as per some condition but some cases it fails. I am explaining my query below.

```
    select b.member_id as b_member_id,
b.rest_name,
b.city,
b.proviance,
b.postal,
b.address,
b.country,
b.person,
b.mobile,
b.url,
b.status,
b.premium,
b.image,
b.business_phone_no,
b.email,
b.multiple_image,
b.latitude,
b.longitude,
b.quadrant,
d.member_id as d_member_id,
d.day_id,
d.cat_id,
d.subcat_id,
d.comment,
d.city,
d.special_images,
c.cat_id,
c.special,
sub.subcat_id,
sub.subcat_name,
sub.status,
sl.day_id,
sl.member_id,
sl.date_from,
sl.date_to 
from db_restaurant_basic as b left join db_restaurant_detail as d on b.member_id=d.member_id
left join db_category as c on d.cat_id=c.cat_id 
left join db_subcategory as sub on d.subcat_id=sub.subcat_id
left join db_special_images as sl on d.day_id=sl.day_id 
where b.city='2' and d.day_id='4' and c.special='1' 
and (((sl.date_from IS NULL or sl.date_from='') and (sl.date_to IS NULL or sl.date_to='')) or( sl.date_from <='2016-10-27' and sl.date_to >= '2016-10-27' )) 
and b.status=1 
and sub.status=1 group by d.subcat_id ORDER BY b_member_id DESC
```

Here my problem is some value also is coming which does not match the condition. Here `b.city='2'` but some value is coming which `city=0` only also. Here i need the value should come as per proper matching. Please help me.

Comment: You have an `or` part in your `WHERE` clause. This may cause this. Read up on boolean logic: AND has higher precedence than OR.

Comment: @BartFriederichs : `(((sl.date_from IS NULL or sl.date_from='') and (sl.date_to IS NULL or sl.date_to='')) or( sl.date_from <='2016-10-27' and sl.date_to >= '2016-10-27' ))` .this condition is inside one bracket and i need this.

Comment: 1. What's the data type of the city field? Is it numeric? If yes, then do not use string for comparison. 2. Can you pls provide some sample output where the output is not what you expect? This would help us narrow down where things may have gone wrong.

Comment: (Why would sl.date_from be blank?)

Comment: @Shadow : Yes ,its int(11).

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting `d.city` - from the `db_restaurant_basic` table - but the condition you set is `b.city='2'` - on the `db_restaurant_detail` table.

So any results with a city of 0, will show the city from the `d` / `db_restaurant_detail` table.

If you need to filter on that as well, you need to add `and d.city=2`.

You should probably check if you can normalize your database structure more to avoid having the same data in different tables.

Answer (score 0):

Using the answer window's formatting options...

```
 WHERE b.city = 2 
   AND d.day_id = 4   -- NOTE THAT THIS IS AN INNER JOIN!
   AND c.special = 1  -- AND SO IS THIS !!
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have city twice in the selection list (b.city and d.city) I have to assume the `city='0'` value you mention is really `d.city='0'`. To make sure that also d.city is '2' you can add an additional condition in the where clause or you specify the join like this

`select ... from db_restaurant_basic as b left join db_restaurant_detail as d on d.member_id=d.member_id and b.city = d.city left join ...`

or even like this, getting rid of the ambiguity

`select ... from db_restaurant_basic as b left join db_restaurant_detail as d using(member_id, city) left join ...`